# Changing a color in CSS changes layout dimensions

Tags: css, colors

I have changed the color of a navigation bar in a phpBB forum style from the default #AA0000 to #941212 (which I found in a HTML color codes tool).  As soon as I did that, everything on the page shifted left and a vertical scrollbar appeared.  Changing the color back to #AA0000 fixes the layout.  Why is a color affecting layout dimensions?

Old code was

```
border-bottom: 7px solid #AA0000;
```

New attempted code was

```
border-bottom: 7px solid #941212;
```

I literally just changed the 6 characters.  Both colors are a shade of red.  I only tested in Chrome (Windows 8 Consumer Preview).  The only idea is that 941212 is an illegal color or something outside the typical supported range for Chrome or something like that.

Comment: can you push your code for better understanding

Comment: it would also help to know what browser and OS this is happening on. Is it all browsers or just a single one?

Comment: Question edited to address comments

Comment: can you provide your website link

Comment: @KnocksX it will be better for us if you can give us an example code

Comment: sandeep: The site is a private project so I can't post a link. @Aniket: I did provide the code above, what other code did you want to see?

Comment: @KnocksX I do see that code snippet. It will be better if you can give us a fiddle or something when you can show us the problem. A little part of the page where on changing the `border-bottom`, the pages shifts. You don't need to give the website link or anything, just make a fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Color ***will never*** effect affect layout size / dimensions.

Something else is going on.

Using a proper browser, like Chrome for example, you can view the computed style of the element which is being presented improperly.

See: [**Chrome Developer Tools: Element Styles**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles).

Comment: I realize that, and that's why I asked the question.  I have edited the question with additional information.